# Cat pawing for water

Tags: cats

One of my two cats are trying to dig trough the floor when ever she's drinking water from her bowl. I have wooden floors, and what used to be a adorable behavior has turned in to something really frustrating. living in a very poorly noise isolated apartment, she wakes me up at night clawing the floor when she's drinking water. Can I do anything at all to get her out of this cute but stupid behavior?

Comment: Tried putting down a thick and durable mat under the bowl?

Comment: I did! Her sister ended up peeing on it. It ain't easy being a single cat dad of two.

Comment: maybe she's digging for oil?

Answer (score 3):

My cat does this when I give him food that he doesn't like: He will stand over his food bowl and scratch the floor with his front paws. Basically, he is trying to bury the food. He used to do the same with his drinking water until I changed his metal drinking bowl for a ceramic one. Now, all is sweetness and light as far as watering is concerned. He is still picky about his chow, though.